# Unable to Parse Time String to specified format

Tags: java, validation, date, datetime, time

I need to compare two time string which i have entered.. I am able to do it for date but for time i am unable to do it. Please find below the code I tried :

My issue is.. -- I am able to get the Time Format according to the Format I enter which will be in String but I am unable to parse it. Because only if parse it I will be able to compare and find out whether varible  Time field to get the difference. Please find below the code  we have done :

```
try{
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
```

**//Assume The format I entered is HH:mm:ss**

```
    df.setLenient(false);

                T1 = new Date();  //here we will get the current Time
                temp_Time = df.format(T1);
```

**// we change to the format we have requested (Example Format – HH:mm:ss. So Temp_Time = 18:20:45).**

```
                T1 = df.parse(temp_Time);
```

**// When we try to parse it we get Thu Jan 01 13:24:40 IST 1970. We are able to parse for Date, only for time format it’s not working.**

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. It's pretty unclear at the moment.

Comment: If you give it just a time, it has to guess the date, so it assumes 1.1.1970. If you want to compare times, it might be better to compare the formatted strings.

Comment: Have you tried something like example 2 at http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-string-to-date-java/?

Answer (score 2):

In order to see how your parse-result looks like (an object of type `java.util.Date`) you have to format it again:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date time = df.parse("18:20:45");

// visualizing the result
System.out.println(df.format(time)); // output: 18:20:45
```

You cannot rely just on `System.out.println(time)` because that code only uses the output of `toString()` of `java.util.Date` which is dependent on the system timezone and prints a whole timestamp based on date 1970-01-01 as date offset (which is used by `SimpleDateFormat` due to lack of date information in input string).

For comparing time strings you should use chronologically descending order (from left to right) like in ISO-8601-format `HH:mm:ss` so here string comparison is sufficient.

**UPDATE because of comment:**

If your ONLY concern to use parsing is to compare the time objects then I still think that string comparison of ISO-formatted time strings is the most simple and straight-forward option because you can leave parsing effort completely. ISO-8601 has even defined its time format "HH:mm:ss" with respect to ordering requirements.

If you have more plans/intentions beyond simple comparisons then you can of course parse the time strings to `Date`-objects and compare these parsed objects on basis of method `getTime()` like in your comment and do other additional stuff with the (ugly and half-deprecated) `Date`-objects.

Comment: Found a Solution
`Date Time1 = new Date();
Date Time2 = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String temp1 = sdf.format(Time1);` **// Get in specified Format 
`String temp2 = "09:00:00";`

`Date d1 = sdf.parse(temp1);` //Output - Thu Jan 01 13:24:40 IST 1970
`Date d2 = sdf.parse(temp2);` //Output - Thu Jan 01 09:00:00 IST 1970
`long y = d1.getTime();`// you will get the time in Milliseconds
`long z = d2.getTime();`// you will get the time in Milliseconds

Now find which is greater and convert back -- 
`d1 = new Date(l);
sdf.format(d1); `
//output - 13:24:40

Comment: @AlexMichaelRaj Thanks for getting more insight into your motivations, although your code example does not fully compile. I have also updated my answer for showing you a simpler alternative. But maybe you really need the `Date`-objects.